# How do I get a UserControl derived class thats bound to ObservableCollection to respond to adds?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, observablecollection, itemssource

My collection seems fine as I am able to use a ListView and it responds correctly to adds, however when I nest a listview into a UserControl it doesn't.  I've provided the pertinent code.

I've created a UserControl derived class in this fashion:

```
public partial class MyCtrl: UserControl
{
    #region Static Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(MyCtrl),
        new PropertyMetadata(MyCtrl.ItemsSourcePropertyChangedCallback));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static void ItemsSourcePropertyChangedCallback(
        DependencyObject controlInstance,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         MyCtrl myInstance=(MyCtrl)controlInstance;
         myInstance.nestedList.ItemsSource=e.NewValue as IEnumerable;
    }
}
```

With the XAML like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyCtrl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="nestedList" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My consuming XAML looks like this:

```
<MyCtrl x:Name="myInstance" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" />
```

Where the collection is defined like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCollectionProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("MyCollection",
       typeof(ObservableCollection<MyObject>),
       typeof(ConsumingObject),
       new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<MyObject>());

public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyCollection
{
    get { return   (ObservableCollection<MyObject>)this.GetValue(MyCollectionProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(MyCollectionProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to register an event handler on `CollectionChanged` if your `ItemSource` is an ObservableCollection< T >

Comment: I'd prefer to use the AutoMagic.  The collections are reporting the add because when I use a ListView instead of the custom UserControl it works.  So somehow I'm not propagating the change to the nested ListView.

Comment: as far as i know, the listbox control checks if that datasource implements INotifyPropertyChanged and handles PropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

This questions maybe can help.
What is the DataContext of myInstance?
Was the code able to go to this line?
**myInstance.nestedList.ItemsSource=e.NewValue as IEnumerable;**
If yes then is nestedList null or not?